# When is a quadratic polynomial over a ring a square?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, square-numbers

We include different cases first and examine them separately. First for integral domain $E$, apparently a quadraric polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is a square in $E[x]$ iff $a, b$ are squares in $E$ and $b^2=4ac$. My pirmary interests for this question is over non-integral domains so here is one example in $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$: $x^2+4x+1$ is not a square in $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z[x]$ but has its discriminant $=0$ and both the first and third coefficient a square in $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$.

I guess this question will not be trivial in a general ring $A$ so mainly I am looking for references to related theorems/books on this topic. And I expect  the following questions being answered if it can:

$(i).$ When is a quadraric polynomial in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$ a square?

$(ii).$ When is a polynomial $Ax^2+Bx+C\in\mathrm{Mat}_n(R)[x]$ a square, when $R$ is a commutative ring with identity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A naive guess for your first question on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ would be that a quadratic polynomial $ax^{2}+bx+c$ is a square if and only if there exists solutions $x_{a},x_{c}$ to the congruence equation $x^{2}\equiv a\pmod{n}$ and $x^{2}\equiv c\pmod{n}$ satisfying $2x_{a}x_{c}\equiv b\pmod{n}$.

Comment: This strongly depends on the [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Case_of_rings) of your ring and which of $4$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ have nontrivial gcd with that characteristic.  In your example, $\gcd(b,12) = \gcd(4,12) \neq 1$, which is an obstruction to the argument you present for IDs.